# Using $in but matching on specific fields

Tags: mongodb

I'm attempting to use $in to query a mongoDB collection. The issue I'm running up against is that the arrays are arrays of JSON objects, not just arrays of a single field. So the full object looks like this:

```
{
    items: [
        {
            name: "Jacket",
            other_field: "1234"
        }
    ]
}
```

So if I have an array that looks like this:

```
[{name:"Jacket", other_field:"3456"}]
```

I'd like to query for documents that contain within their items array any object which has a matching name field, ignoring all other fields. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$elemMatch` for this.

Example -

```
db.users.find({items: { $elemMatch: {name:'Jacket'} } } )
```

For more understanding, you can refer to - [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)

Answer (score 0):

As per your question there should be two possibilities if your documents structure looks like below

```
    {
    items: [
    {
        name: "Jacket",
        other_field: "1234"
    }
    ]
 }
```

In this case you use following query

```
db.collectionName.find({"items.name":"Jacket"},{"items":1})
```

so above query will return only matching items.name matching criteria.
And another more possibilities if your documents structure looks like nested as below

```
    {
    items: [
    {
        name: "Jacket",
        other_field: "1234"
    },
    {
        name: "Jacket",
        other_field: "12345"
    },
    {
        name: "Jacket2",
        other_field: "1234e"
    }
    ]
}
```

In this case should use `aggregate` function as below

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
    "$unwind": "$items"
},
{
    "$match": {
    "items.name": "Jacket"
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "items.name": 1,
    "items.other_field": 1
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your requirement correctly then could could ask

```
db.collectionName.find({'items.name': 'Jacket'})
```

MongoDB automatically does the "descending down" into the arrays and pick the ones that match.

fricke